# MATLAB Generate matrix with logical values according to vector

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a vertical Nx1 matrix A full of integers.

```
A:
+---+
| 4 |
| 3 |
| 1 |
| . |
+---+
```

My goal is to create a NxM matrix B where each cell's value is 1 if it's row is less than or equal to the corresponding number in A and the rest are 0.

```
B:
+-------------+
| 1 1 1 1 0 . |
| 1 1 1 0 0 . |
| 1 0 0 0 0 . |
| . . . . . . |
+-------------+
```

This could be achieved by iterating row by row, but I'm trying to find a quicker method. I feel this could be done through logical indexing but cannot think of how to exactly off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can type:

```
B = A>=1:size(A,1)
% or, in versions earlier than 2016b:
B = bsxfun(@ge,A,1:size(A,1))
```

This will [compare each value](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/compatible-array-sizes-for-basic-operations.html) in `A` to all the numbers between `1` to the length of `A`, and returns `1` if it's greater or equals ([`@ge`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ge.html)...) to it, and `0` if not. The result is a matrix, where each row *k* is the comparison for the value `A(k)` with all values between `1` to the length of `A`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. Size(A,1) would give N, the height of the A vector. 1:size(A,1) would give a horizontal vector 1,2,...N. When I execute A>=1:size(A,1), MATLAB errors saying Matrix dimensions must agree. I understand what you're trying to do with comparing a vertical vector and a horizontal vector to get the matrix, but the syntax doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution for my problem.

```
    index = repmat(1:max(A),length(A),1);
    B = ones(length(A),max(A));
    B(index>repmat(A,1,max(A))) = 0;
```

index is a NxM matrix where the value of a cell is equal to its column number. Whenever that value is greater than the value in A, the corresponding cell in B is set to 0.